# Publishing from Author to Public in Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I am just trying out Magnolia CMS. I have hit a stumbling block.

My steps:

1. Followed the [hello-magnolia tutorial](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Hello+Magnolia). That all works fine in Author (localhost) mode.
2. Clicked Publish (including sub-nodes)
3. Go to the public site (on my localhost http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/Hello-Magnolia)
4. I get a server 500 error that looks like this:

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException:
>   info.magnolia.registry.RegistrationException:
>   hello-magnolia:pages/hello

I have tried publishing EVERYTHING in Author and restarting the server, but so far the error remains.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same error by **not deploying** the `hello-world` folder to the Magnolia **public** instance. I just downloaded the latest Magnolia version and the hello-world tutorial.

Most probably, you have not deployed the `hello-world` folder (I downloaded and unzipped the complete sample from the Magnolia wiki site) to `<magnolia-5.4.7>/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/webapps/magnoliaPublic` but only to `<magnolia-5.4.7>/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/webapps/magnoliaAuthor`.

It needs to be in both! When you publish something via Magnolia, you (usually) only publish content pages or assets, which rely on templates inside the `hello-world` folder, and the Magnolia public instance also needs to know about the templates it should use. `magnoliaAuthor` and `magnoliaPublic` are two separate applications, so they don't know about each other directly, nor about the templates deployed on each.

(Tomcat restart required after copying it to there.)

[image]

Comment: Perfect instructions. Thank you for that Mathias. It has worked! I assumed everything was being published over from Author to Public. Obviously that is not the case. This does however make perfect sense. Thanks for your help.